# IF type stement in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, if-statement

Im trying to create a query in MySQL based on an IF type statement but am unsure how to script it.
Im new to MySQL and database querying in general, so if convention dictates that this type of query is created further upstream just say.

For context I have 4 fields:

`ID, YEAR, SYSTEM, MEASURE`

I want to identify all `ID` where difference between `YEAR = '2015'` and `YEAR = '2014'` is greater than `500`.

I'm not sure if you do this via an IF statement, in the WHERE clause, or use two SELECT statements.

I have not been required to do such a complex query on a database before

Comment: Can you clarify a little bit more about the if statement? What does it mean "difference" between 2015 and 2014?

Comment: Can you share some sample data, its a bit unclear what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.id_farm, a.id_year, a.measure > b.measure + 500 AS test
FROM t1 AS a
INNER JOIN(
        SELECT id_farm, measure
        FROM t1
        WHERE id_year = 2014) AS b
ON a.id_farm = b.id_farm
WHERE id_year = 2015
HAVING test = 1
```

i have not come across HAVING but after figuring out how to write it, it does now seem simple!

Answer (score 0):

SQL (MySQL and other systems) basically works with sets of rows. So, let me guess, and try to recast your requirement in terms of such sets.

"I want the set of `ID` values for the year 2015 where they are more than 500 greater than the largest value for 2014. "

To translate that specification of a set you do this SQL

```
       SELECT ID
         FROM table
        WHERE YEAR = '2015'
          AND ID > (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM table WHERE YEAR='2014')
```

Explanation:

This chooses just the ID value from each matching row. You get a result set with an ID in each row.

```
       SELECT ID
```

This names the table that's the starting point for your set.

```
         FROM table
```

This filters out all rows for any year other than 2015

```
        WHERE YEAR = '2015'
```

This is the trick. It runs *another* select statement to find the largest ID value in the table for the year 2014. It then filters your 2015 ID values to choose only those with values more than 500 greater than the largest in 2014.

```
          AND ID > (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM table WHERE YEAR='2014')
```

Now, I may have guessed wrong about what you want. But I hope this discussion will help you think in terms where your specification can be handled with SQL.

Comment: thank you, i obviously phrased the question poorly, but this put me on the right track. i wanted to find IDs where the measure in 2015 was greater than the 2014 by 500.. i managed it. i have put it in an answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you mean the ID difference, but the measurement of a specific system from 2014 to 2015.  If this is accurate, you could do something like a primary query criteria of 2015 and do a JOIN to 2014 for the same system and measurement difference.

```
select
      T1.ID,
      T1.Year,
      T1.System,
      T1.Measure,
      T2.Measure as Measure2014,
      T1.Measure - T2.Measure as MeasureDifference
   from
      YourTable T1
         JOIN YourTable T2
            on T1.System = T2.System
           AND T2.Year = 2014
           AND T1.Measure - T2.Measure > 500
   where
      T1.Year = 2015
```

Not sure of your measurements, but you may need to apply an ABSOLUTE value check on the difference.